# Resigning from moderator duties

Tags: discussion, moderators

Sorry. At the moment I cannot handle the duties of a diamond bearer with the patience it requires.

This job forces one to encounter all the worst the site has to offer. My approach to the job (and to the entire site) is emotional, possibly too much so. This combination has drained the reserves of naïve optimism that propelled me earlier.

Time in the sewer has desensitized me to some things, blurring the distinction between violations of actual site policies and violations of what I personally see as proper use of the site. This has caused me to lash out at individuals even though the problems are systemic. Not. Good. Better that I quit lest I cause some real damage with the mod tools.

I will reduce my hours here, but won't quit using the site entirely. May be concentrate on the things that made me fall in love with this site in the first place? I contact the community managers, they will remove my diamond when they get around to it. Together with the remaining moderators they will decide if they want to recruit reinforcements. Please give your support to them as you have supported me.

Not to end on a sad note:

- The world is not black and white. We have a rainbow. The spectrum (of opinions) is not necessarily even just 1-dimensional.
- Educating each other is the best way forward.

Comment: You are one of the heroes of this site, Sir, because you did the thankless job of  moderating a community with ever growing size better than anybody can. This is all down to your passion and dedication, second to none.Thank.You. Hope that your replacement, if any , can do even half the job you did for the site.

Comment: Thank you Jyrki for your work. Good luck, and I hope you enjoy some well-deserved time away.

Comment: It's always sad to see someone who's done a good job leave. We will try to do well with your turgid advice (and that would be three dollars, please).

Comment: You did a very good job. Yes, you got very emotional at times, but this doesn't affect the quality of your work. And it shows that you care deeply about this forum.

Comment: Sad to see you go, Jyrki.

Comment: What they said.

Comment: Thank you for all your work, @JyrkiLahtonen. Your contributions have really been a wonderful thing to see here.

Comment: I'm reluctant to upvote this post, because I hope you realize upvotes are NOT to indicate pleasure at your resignation.  You have been a fabulous moderator on MSE, and in part because of your full investment in it, including the emotional aspects. I think this site is better with you, than without you,  and I believe you are one of three of the best mods on this site, ever.  I'll be sad to see you not working as a mod, but I support your decision.  Most of all, I look forward to your continued participation on MSE.

Comment: This is sad, but I understand. You are/were an excellent moderator and I am grateful for all the work you put in the site. I hope you can still contribute in what ways you feel emotionally able to. Thanks for all your work in the site.

Comment: Are you *really* sure, Jyrki? Even before joining the mod team, you always striked me as a very balanced and thoughtful person, and I believe you are *perfectly* fit for the job. On the other hand I also understand the side effects of an *emotional imbalance* on one's life, and the sensation of *being handcuffed* to something toxic. But I surely will miss you as a guide, if you really plan to put away the diamond.

Comment: I am sad to see you leave the mod team, but I am glad you'll still be around on the site! Now you get to see those eyes looking out from the sewer grate out of the sides of your eyes. Remember, moderation without emotion would be a pretty stale job.

Comment: Thank you Jyrki, I'll miss you on the team! Nobody is made for this task, but you were pretty darn good at it.

Comment: I was reluctant to comment since there has been a lot of comments already, but you deserve such praise. Thank you for the dedication you have bestowed upon this site.

Comment: I had very few direct interactions with you. But in all of that what stroke me as particularly impressive was your frankness about your position on a particular issue - a quality which is really rare.

Comment: As I'm sure, one of the people you lost patience with, I'm still enormously grateful for the help you gave over the past year or so. I said before, I think this frustration arises out of brilliant mathematicians having to coach some of the biggest nincompoops like me, which is ultimately a waste of your true talents. Please be reassured that even the times you spent tearing your hair out, seemingly in the sewer, have been invaluable to me and others.  Take some time off and I hope you can come back with renewed vigour.

Comment: I'm quite new here , but ive always admired people like you. Thank you for your service dear sir.Hope you continue to help this site flourish

Comment: Hang in there, Jyrki! I'm glad that the experience hasn't soured you to the community at large. :-)

Comment: You were easily the best mod that I ever communicated with.

Comment: This got so many likes it's netted Jyrki another gold badge. What a nice send-off gift.

Comment: I'm really sorry for that! I've always really appreciated your correct and balanced action as moderator here on MSE and I think it is really a heavy loss for the whole community! Hope to see you often as a contributor, the absence of the diamond will not make me lose esteem towards you.

Comment: What I really like in the MathSE is that I don't have talk with its mods (as mods). This is why do I like you all.

Comment: This is sad. Thank you for your efforts, they are appreciated; you are worn because you care. Caring is good.

Comment: Well, I will miss your diamond and your consumate skills as a moderator; clearly, the best and most even-handed I have seen.. My wish is that your sense of joy and fun in this mad web place return to you.  I too am saddened but encourage you do do what you know is best for yourself.  Fortunately for us here this is not really a farewell, just a change in the guard.  All my best.

Comment: Your introspection just makes you ever more adequate for this role. I know you're not leaving the site, but your name is one that is bound to its history. - that's impact. Thank you.

Comment: I hope you stay around.

Comment: Sorry to see this place has gotten to you.  I always enjoyed your posts and comments since they were some of the most insightful and level-headed contributions I've read in this ever-worsening dumpster fire of a site.  Wishing you continued success here and elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you very much for the work you have done as a moderator ! I am sure that every one will miss you. Cheers.

Comment: thanks for all of your efforts in both moderating and providing good content, i wish all the best going forward!

Comment: You've always seemed like a gentleman; I would never guess you had lashed out at anyone.  I do think there are some inherent flaws in the site design that pit people against each other.  Probably better for the site owner to fix those than to continue to traumatize the moderators....

Comment: I feel like this is a bit over-dramatic, you could have just contacted various moderators instead of broadcasting everything.

Comment: Jyrki I miss you as a mod, but I welcome working with you as a colleague too.  But what is one to do when working  as a regular user begins to make one feel miserable much of the time; more cynical then ever, no longer here for the joy it once brought?  Give up?  That's what the element I don't want to support may want.  Stick around?  And be frustrated, angry, and just plain stop caring?  I'll never stop caring, but out of care, and my love of math, I may need to leave altogether.  I hope you find your peace as a participant.  I'm still trying to find mine.

Comment: @user189728  Just reveals how much of a newbie you are to the site at the time of posting your comment.  You're a baby here. If you're human, and sane, you'll grow up and form attachments with users you've worked along side for four, five, six, seven, eight or more years.  Sad that you aren't yet able to appreciate human stepping stones, one of which is graduation, and another, retirement.  I'll cross my fingers you're not a bot.

Comment: @amWhy well, I am barely 18

Comment: But I do realize developing a sense of community with others, and attachment, or collegiate respect for and from one another takes, perhaps, more than three months, so @user189728, forgive me my impatience, if you will.

Comment: @amWhy I was actually drunk when I posted that, so I’m sorry for saying it

Comment: @user189728 No worries; I've been there, in a similarly positioned situation.  It's certainly nothing anyone will hold against you! Cheers!

Comment: Rest well, good sir.

Comment: Sorry to see you go. Thanks for the hard work.